# Adding years to a date in angular4

Tags: angular

I am using *angular 4* and I want to add **5** **years** to a date when the methods call.I have referred the previous answered questions but still my code doesn't work.

> [ERROR TypeError: this.ExpiryDateAutoGen.getFullYear is not a
>   function]

I think there should be a small change to my code to be correct.

Please help and thanks in advance

**component.ts** code

```html
 ExpiryDateAutoGen: Date;

this.ExpiryDateAutoGen = this.EffectiveDate;
    this.ExpiryDateAutoGen.setDate(this.ExpiryDateAutoGen.getFullYear() + 5);
```

Comment: I would suggest a visit to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) , >The setDate() method sets the day of the Date object relative to the beginning of the currently set month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function getFullYear() only works if your ExpiryDateAutoGen object is of type Date. Make sure that's the case.

Here is an working example for you.

```
var date = new Date("December 5, 2018 12:20:00");
var num = date.getFullYear();
```

This will give me

```
2018
```

Comment: ExpiryDateAutoGen is a Date property as you can see I have displayed it in my code. Is it the problem for this matter ?

Comment: @Shyamal What's the object type of EffectiveDate?

Comment: thanks I changed my code according to your structure and now it works

Answer (score 1):

I found a method

```html
this.ExpiryDateAutoGen = new Date(this.EffectiveDate);
    this.ExpiryDateAutoGen.setUTCFullYear(this.ExpiryDateAutoGen.getUTCFullYear() + 5);
```